# How can I redirect_to a specific div on a page that has been hidden and now needs to be shown

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

My HTML:

```
<div class="menu">
    <a href="javascript:displayonediv('sections1');">Energy Profile</a>
    <a href="javascript:displayonediv('sections2');">Statistics</a>
</div>

<div name="sections" id="sections1">
    .... some stuff ....
</div>
<div name="sections" id="sections2">
    .... some stuff ....
</div>
```

My JavaScript code:

```
function displayonediv(choosendiv) {
    $('div[name|="sections"]').each(function(index) {
        if ($(this).attr("id") == choosendiv) {
            $(this).show(200);
        }
        else {
            $(this).hide(200);
        }
    });
}
```

By default, the `div` with `id=sections1` displays when the page loads while the `div` with `id=sections2` is hidden. In my controller after I submit a form I am redirecting to the `div` with `id=sections2`. However, I cannot seem to redirect to that page and load that specific div (`id=sections2`). I have tried to use anchor tags but my efforts have been in vain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should do something like this:

Hide all the sections in CSS so that they not even visible during load:

```
#sections1, #sections2 {
    display: none;
}
```

The CSS is optional. Use this simple function to do the dynamic show and hide:

```
function displayonediv(chosendiv) {
    //Make sure all other divs are really hidden if there are subsequent calls:
    $("div[name^=sections]").hide(200);
    $("#" + chosendiv).show(200);
}
```

Also:

If that doesn't work and you are able to change that terrible HTML then change the HTML as follows.

```
<div class="menu">
    <a class="section" href="#sections1">Energy Profile</a>
    <a class="section" href="#sections2">Statistics</a>
</div>

<div class="sections" id="sections1">
    .... some stuff ....
</div>
 <div class="sections" id="sections2">
    .... some stuff ....
</div>
```

And have this js:

```
$("a.section").click(function(event) {
    $("div.sections").hide(200);
    $($(this).attr('href')).show(200);
});
```

As with most things in jQuery, all your code should be `$(function(){ /*here*/});`.

To make the section load when the page is loaded:

```
$(function() {
    $(window.location.hash).show(200);
});
```

Comment: thanks for the recommendations, but now none of the divs display when i click the links after adjusting the html as suggested. Also my original code worked(untidy and bad, i know) except the problem i was having was that i could not redirect to a specific div. For example i would redirect to the sections2 div (my url would be as follows http://......//?#sections2) and sections1 div would load. Any thoughts?

Comment: Ah, my apologies, made a typo. Thank you for helping me. Much Appreciated. All works now

Comment: whoops, if i redirect to this url nothing is displayed "http://......#sections2". It only works when i click on the links.

Comment: Ok added that info to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `|` after name and replace it with `$` or leave it without. I'd even remove the name part from the `div` and add a class to them instead and use `$('.sections').each()`.